# Using Gaussian copulas to address endogeneity

Tags: copula, endogeneity

I am trying to replicate the paper of [Park and Gupta (2012)](http://papers.ssrn.com/sol3/papers.cfm?abstract_id=2025669) that handle endogeneity using Gaussian copulas - they are basically modelling the correlation between the regressor and the error.

Here is the model:

[image]

With [image] being the marginal density functions, then, using Gaussian copula, the joint density function is:
[image], where [image] are marginal distribution functions.

Then the likelihood function, should be:

[image], where

[image] and [image] is the normal density with mean 0 and variance sigma^2.

Make the notation:
[image] and generate them from a multivariate normal distribution having covariance R and mean=0:

[image]
from where I then recover P and the error, xi, and then I optimize the likelihood function.
P should not be normal, so I generate it as a t-distribution, and the error should be normally distributed. Below is the R code.

**The problem is that, generating 1000 samples, with sample size=400, and true parameter values: a=-1, rho = 0.5 and sigma = 1, I do not get values close enough to the true parameters - I obtain (a, rho, sigma)=(-0.718, 0.498, 0.88 ).**

Of course, everything depends on the initial guess, but even with close values I do not get results good enough.

Anyone can help maybe to point out where is my mistake?

```
install.packages(optimx);install.packages(MASS)
library(MASS); library(optimx)

Tn <- 400      # sample size
rho1 <- 0.5      # corr(eps,P) = rho
R <- matrix(c(1,rho1,0,rho1,1),2,2)      # correlation matrix
m <- c(0,0)   #mean
sim <- 1000             # no. simulations
a.cop <- rep(0,sim); rho.cop <- rep(0,sim); sigma.cop <- rep(0,sim)

logLL <- function(theta){  # Likelihood Function
a1 <- theta[1]; rho <- theta[2]; sig.eps <- theta[3]
s <- sum(rho^2*(P.star^2 + eps.star^2)/(2*(1-rho^2)) - (rho*P.star*eps.star)/(1-rho^2))
ee <- y-a1*P
l.eps <- sum(dnorm(ee,mean=0,sd=sig.eps, log=TRUE))
mm <- (-Tn/2)*log(1-rho^2)
logll <- mm - s + l.eps
ll <- -1* logll;  return(ll)
}

for (i in 1:sim) {
# generate multivariate normal with e.star, P.star 
N <- mvrnorm(Tn,mu=m,Sigma=R)
eps.star <- N[,1]
P.star <- N[,2]
eps <- qnorm(pnorm(eps.star))   # epsilon is normally distributed
P <- qt(pnorm(P.star),3)        # P has a t-distribution with df=3
y <- a*P + eps
# inital guess for parameters
a1 <- -0.3 ;  rho <- 0.1 ;   sig.eps <- 0.5
param <- c(a1,rho,sig.eps)
a.cop[i]     <- optimx(par=param,fn=logLL,method="BFGS")$p1
rho.cop[i]   <- optimx(par=param,fn=logLL,method="BFGS")$p2
sigma.cop[i] <- optimx(par=param,fn=logLL,method="BFGS")$p3
}; mean(a.cop); mean(rho.cop); mean(sigma.cop)
```